# Libgdx Table Confusion

Tags: android, libgdx, tablelayout

I'm trying to display in a vertical and centered way an Image, and a button for my Screen Menu.

I've almost accomplished that only using actors but I decided that maybe a layout would be the best practice here.

So I've done:

```
  public MenuScreen(final MyGame myGame) {
    this.myGame = myGame;
        font = new BitmapFont();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 480, 800);
        stage = new Stage();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        stage.getViewport() .setCamera(camera);
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("menu/glassy-ui.json"));

        button = new TextButton("NEW GAME", skin);
        button.setTransform(true);
         button.setScale(0.5f);

        button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                myGame.setScreen(new GameScreen( myGame));
            }
        });
        Image imageLogo = new Image( new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("titleLogo.png")));
       // imageLogo.setScaling(Scaling.fit);

        Table myTable = new Table();
        myTable.setFillParent(true);
        myTable .add(imageLogo);// .width(imageLogo.getWidth()).height(imageLogo.getHeight()).row()   ;

        myTable.row() ;
        myTable.add(button);

        stage.addActor(myTable);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update(); 
        batch.begin();
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
        batch.end();
    }
```

But it seems that the viewport of the stage isn't affecting the table area which goes offscreen and I'm not even sure that the image is displayed...

This is what I see :
[image: menu screen snapshot]

Tried to read wiki and approaches of other developers.
For what I've read everyone has different system to accomplish that goal, nobody used a camera, and I suspect that's my real problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stage.setDebugAll(true);   //enable debug mode and check what's going on 

camera.setToOrtho(false, 480, 800);
```

By this you're setting viewport of camera by a fix value. You are not resizing/scaling any Actor so make sure all your actor should have size in the context of 480, 800.

```
camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,1);
```

This will move your camera in center.